# Integrating dokuwiki inside an existing site

Tags: dokuwiki

I'd like to integrate dokuwiki as part of a Bootstrap site, within a div. Is this possible? I've tried a php include:

```
  <?php include('dokuwiki/index.php'); ?>
```

but this effectively redirects - it just generates a completely new page, replacing the existing html. Note that the Bootstrap plugin doesn't do the job.

Comment: `index.php` redirects to `doku.php` (https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/master/index.php). You could try `<?php include('dokuwiki/doku.php'); ?>`

Comment: Already tried that, unfortunately.

Comment: I thought I'd tried that, but I hadn't - it does get me a lot closer. I now get a basic wiki page, with the Bootstrap structure around it, but I've lost most of the site (maybe everything in a tab?)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution, it might be the time to use an [HTML Frame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp).